# Differences between NetTcpBinding and NetPeerTcpBinding

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

What is the practical difference between NetTcpBinding and NetPeerTcpBinding in WCF? When should I pick one over another?

Comment: If you read the remarks from documentation for both you should get enough of an idea about their differences between  [NetTcpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/nettcpbinding#remarks) and [NetPeerTcpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/netpeertcpbinding#remarks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Peer Network binding**
>
> This binding is provided by the NetPeerTcpBinding class. It uses TCP
>   protocol but uses peer net-working as transport. In this networking
>   each machine (node) acts as a client and a server to the other nodes.
>   This is used in the file sharing systems like torrent.
>
> **TCP binding**
>
> This binding is provided by the NetTcpBinding class. It uses TCP
>   protocol for communication be-tween two machines with in intranet
>   (means same network). It encodes the message in binary format. This is
>   faster and more reliable binding as compared to the Http protocol
>   bindings. It is only used when communication is WCF - to – WCF means
>   both client and service should have WCF.

More info about bindings: 
[Bindings](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/wcf/understanding-various-types-of-wcf-bindings)

In simple words: 
practical difference is that NetTCP have server side and client side applications, in peer2peer application is working for both client, and server for other clients. P2P is good for file shering (like torrent). NetTCP is better for "normal" apps, where you have server with connection to data store, and clients who use server to get access to data, and server logic.

Answer (score 0):

**TCP binding**

**NetTcpBinding** 
Offered by the NetTcpBinding class, TCP binding uses TCP for cross-machine communication
on the intranet. It supports a variety of features, including reliability,
transactions, and security, and is optimized for WCF-to-WCF communication. As
a result, it requires both the client and the service to use WCF

**Peer network binding**

Offered by the **NetPeerTcpBinding** class, this uses peer networking as a transport:
the peer-network-enabled client and services all subscribe to the same grid and
broadcast messages to it. Peer networking  requires an understanding of grid topology and mesh computing strategies. People those who choose the peer bindings do so because they
are really after an implicit discovery mechanism or a publish-subscribe mechanism.